# PowerShell Import-GPO: Operation not valid

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting, windows-server-2019, gpo

Afternoon everyone. I'm running into an issue I'm not sure how to handle. I'm working on a script for work to deploy a Domain Controller using PSremoting. It all works well in fine until I get to where I'm importing some GPOs from backups.
*All the commands are run under `invoke-command`

I run the command `Import-GPO -BackUpName $GPO -TargetName $GPO -Path $GPOPath -MigrationTable $MigTable -CreateIfNeeded`

When I run this, I get an error on the host:

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Import-GPO], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.InvalidOperationException,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.ImportGpoCommand
    + PSComputerName        : v204-DC1
```

I can't seem to find anything that says what this means. When I check for the GPOs on the DC, they all show up and seem to be linked properly. I am curious what this error is, or if I should just append `-ErrorAction SilentlyContinue` to the end of my code.

Answer (score -1):

Ended up being an issue with my migration table. I rolled back to an earlier one and ended up being good to go